# getfield() not working in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

This is the testing code I wrote to display an ad on a site. It does not display the link and image. I have added the link and image using default settings.

```
   <?php
      if(1){
            echo("<div style='position:absolute; right:142.5px; top:0px; top:303px;'>
            <a href='");
            echo get_field( 'add_ad_link' );
            echo("'><img src=').get_field( 'ad_image' ).('></a></div>");
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: you can  store one variable and assign variable inside.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the correct field names and this is within your loop then you just need to correct your quotes.

```
<?php if (1) : ?>
    <div style='position:absolute; right:142.5px; top:0px; top:303px;'>
        <a href="<?php echo get_field( 'add_ad_link' ); ?>">
            <img src="<?php echo get_field( 'ad_image' ); ?>">
        </a>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

If you are going to be outputting a large amount of HTML it is sometimes easier to read if you just output the HTML instead of trying to echo a string of html. This makes it easier to keep your quotes in the right order.

Comment: It still displays the href and img values empty. Weird.

Comment: Just learned that the code works. I need to have the same value of the ACF for all of the posts and blog page. How can I achieve this? Currently its displaying only on individual posts and in them on only those which are updated after adding ACF.

Comment: If you need to display some custom information across multiple pages consider creating an options page and add your custom fields to the options page. This will make them easier for access as they won't be tied to a specific page/post. ACF option pages are part of ACF Pro. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/options-page/